# PHP GUI Editor (Eclipse)

Tags: php

Mostly I have worked with GWT so PHP for me is still new. I there something like a GUI editor for PHP? for Eclipse? Because with GWT there is a GUI editor to allow designers to develop web application UI graphically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a version of Eclipse that goes with PHP. It is called PDT. [Here is the download link](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/). You should download xDebug seperately as well which is need to debug your php application where you can step into code. This is quite powerful.

Netbeans is another GUI that is popular with PHP developer.

Comment: Neither however offers a GUI editor (an editor to create GUIs).

Comment: I am afraid not, I have never heard of WYSIWYG editor for PHP and I think it is not a good idea anyhow. Look at ASP.NET, I always end up working in code instead of GUI editor. It is always limited and not powerful as hand coded.